# SQL Server Management Studio will not redirect output from command line

Tags: r, sql-server, logging, command-line, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL Server Agent to run a few scripts regularly of type CmdExec with the following format:
`"Absolute path to RScript.exe" "Absolute path to script.R" > "Absolute path to log folder\logfilename.txt"`

This line will work when used manually in the command prompt but won't create a log file when executed through SSMS. Anyone else have trouble dealing with SSMS or is there a problem with my line?

What also works (in the sense that a file is created) in SSMS is `type nul > "Absolute path to log folder\logfilename.txt"` so there is no problem with the file path or write permissions.

Comment: SSMS doesn't run command line commands, so I really don't follow what your opening statement is saying here.

Comment: You can: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-cmdexec-job-step?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: That's not SSMS, that's SQL Server Agent...

Comment: that expains why my google searches were not successful ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this piping is possible for "normal" commands, but under Step Properties -> Advanced, you can choose to save output to file

Comment: Yeah I found this option now too. Also if one wants to really to it manually you can type: cmd.exe \c [command] > outputfile.txt

Comment: Calling a .bat file which redirects the output also works

Comment: bat file sounds like the best way, then you have full control

Comment: Yeah, I also want the date and time included in the outputfilename so I did it with a .bat file